# Accessing protected static members of Superclass by Sub-classes in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I have a question. If I have a static member in the superclass, how do I allow all sub-classes of this superclass access and use the static member.

E.g.

```
/*Superclass*/
class Commands {
   protected:
            static Container database;
};

/*Sub class*/
class Add: public Commands {
   public:
            void add_floating_entry(std::string task_description);  
};

/*This gives me an error. add_floating_task is a method of the Container Class*/
void Add::add_floating_entry(string task_description)
{
   database.add_floating_task(task_description);
}
```

May I know what is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The Container class is as follows

```
class Container {
private:
   vector<Task_Info*> calendar[13][32];
   vector<Task_Info*> task_list;
public:
   void add_floating_task(std::string task_description);
};
```

The error given is: "Use of undeclared identifier "database"

Comment: "This gives me an error." - that doesn't help, there's no one generic C++ error.

Comment: Show the definition of `Container` and the error message, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define that `static` member out of the class declaration:

```
class Commands {
protected:
   static Container database; // <-- It's just a declration
};

Container Commands::database; // <-- You should make a definition
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not
>   a definition ... The definition for a static data member shall appear
>   in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.

Your way to make it `protected` is OK to make it accessible for derived classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still pretty uncomfortable to switch from Java to C++.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok except *missing definition of static Commands member database*.
You need to define `database` outside `commands` class

```
Container Commands::database;
```

§ **9.4.2 Static members**

> **Static members obey the usual class member access rules (Clause 11)**. When used in the declaration of a class member, the static specifier shall only be used in the member declarations that appear within the member-specification of the class definition.

As `database` is a protected member of base class `Commands`, derived class `Add` should be able to access it by `::` operator or `.` operator from object.

Answer (score 0):

Since `static` member is shared between all objects.`Commands::database` should be OK.